# Settings disappear after update

Tags: updates, gnome-settings-daemon

My settings panel disappear after Ubuntu's update in Ubuntu 23.10. If I noticed well I read the update of Ubuntu Base. I restored this by the terminal command gnome-control-center display but after next updates it disappear again. Is this a bug or does it have anything to do with my laptop? [image]